# Add Bootstrap to available external libraries

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I've used the stack snippets feature a couple of times today (and love it!) by answering a couple of [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) questions. It would be useful to include Bootstrap as well as jQuery, [D3.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D3.js) and [AngularJs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS) as available external libraries.

For now I'm just doing a copy&paste from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ which is the official [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).

Comment: This seems like an opportunity ripe for exploitation by folks willing to [create and use userscripts](http://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts) to customize this tool for individual authors' preferences.

Comment: I suppose I could make my own userscript (already got one to keep the banner at top of screen fixed to the top of the screen!) I do however wonder where the current list of libraries came from. I can get on board with jQuery and Angular, but D3?

Comment: I had proposed [a more general solution](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271776/2333214) @ MSO

Answer (score 1):

As you've already indicated, you can use the `external library` button to add any lib you'd like. You can also copy-paste CDN links into your HTML directly.

I have to go with Shog on this one. Ultimately we all have our library preferences for things like Stack Snippets, and while I wish I could dedicate time to including (and maintaining/keeping up with) 50 of them, I think that user scripts are very likely the best answer here. That way, you can have *exactly* what you want and customize Stack Snippets to be exactly what you're looking for!

Comment: The external library button doesn't really do anything useful for me other than add in the HTML elements for script/link tags. I also need to remember the CDN path for them, and for Bootstrap, there is more than one. I'd be happy with the external links popup to be modded a bit to include some popular libs, so choose from a dropdown or enter your own. Either way I'm more than happy with the feature!